# Calculation of quantiles of a uniform distribution over a sphere

Tags: uniform-distribution, spheres, quantile

How do we calculate quantiles of a uniform distribution over a sphere ?
Can anyone provide me with a tutorial ?

Comment: Is it over a ball? Assume it has radius $1$. One might be interested in say first decile, $r=\sqrt[3}{1/10}$.

Comment: The messed up LaTeX is supposed to be $\sqrt[3]{1/10}$.

Comment: yes, sir.. it is over a ball ! :)

but sir, how do I calculate quantiles in general ?

Answer (score 0):

The question needs some interpretation. I will assume that we have a uniform distribution over a ball of radius $c$. If $P$ is a "randomly chosen" point in the ball, let $X$ be the distance of $P$ from the centre of the ball. We are interested in the various quantiles of $X$.

For example, let us compute the $60$-th percentile of $X$. This is the number $x=x_{0.6}$ such that $\Pr(X\le x)=0.6$.  The probability that $X$ is $\le x$ is the volume of the ball of radius $x$ divided by the volume of the whole ball. This ratio is $\frac{x^3}{c^3}$. Thus we want 
$$\frac{x^3}{c^3}=0.6.$$
Solve. We get
$$x=x_{0.6}=c\sqrt[3]{0.6}.$$ 
Any other quantile that we want is computed in the same way.